# How to format the date in Xamarin Label with StringFormat?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

I want to format the date like that: `yy-MM-dd`

I trying to format the date like that:

```
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Dat, StringFormat='{0:dd.MM}'}" XAlign="Start" YAlign="Center" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="13"/>
```

but I receive full year - `yyyy`

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: why are you using `dd.MM` if you want `yy-MM-dd`?  Is `Dat` a `DateTime` or a `string`?

Comment: Dat is a string ..

Comment: You can't apply date formats to a string.  They only work with DateTime.  Storing dates as strings is a bad idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve "yy-MM-dd" format by using **ToString("yy-MM-dd")** method in the code behind.Below is the code snippets for your reference:

```
<Label  Text="{Binding Dat}"></Label>
```

in page.cs:

```
    public string Dat { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Dat = DateTime.Now.ToString("yy-MM-dd");
        BindingContext = this;
    }
```

[image]